# akka multi-jvm test have to be explicitly run

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

When using the sbt "multi-jvm:test" command, sbt reports there are no tests to run. However, if I explicitly run the test, e.g. "multi-jvm:run package.testName" then they run fine.

I'm using the default convention of {TestName}MultiJvm{NodeName}, and the default path of src/multi-jvm/scala

Edit:

Here's what happens when I run test-only

```
multi-jvm:test-only multijvm.commands.CommandsAreSentToRegisteredHandlers_
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /mnt/repos/akkesb/target/classes...
[info] No tests to run.
```

But here is how I can make it run

```
> multi-jvm:run multijvm.commands.CommandsAreSentToRegisteredHandlers_
[info] * multijvm.commands.CommandsAreSentToRegisteredHandlers_
[JVM-_MarketingServiceHost] [ERROR] [06/10/2013 20:22:30.608] [akkesb-akka.actor
```

Here is my marker:

```
> multi-jvm:multi-jvm-marker
[info] MultiJvm
```

Defined tests:

```
> multi-jvm:multi-jvm-marker
[info] MultiJvm
```

Comment: Have you followed the detailed instructions here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/dev/multi-jvm-testing.html

Comment: Yes, that is where I learned about multi-jvm testing

Answer (score 1):

1) please check your `multiJvmMarker in MultiJvm`

I have `multiJvmMarker in MultiJvm := "_j"`

So tests without `_j` suffix are not running

2) please check your `definedTests in MultiJvm`

I have for example `definedTests in MultiJvm <<= definedTests in Test`

You must see something like

```
> show multi-jvm:defined-tests
[info] List(Test org.digimead.digi.lib.rudp.RUDPTest_j1 : subclass(false, org.scalatest.Suite), Test org.digimead.digi.lib.rudp.RUDPTest_j2 : subclass(false, org.scalatest.Suite)
```

Did your test start with `test-only`? Actually I may start it with

`multi-jvm:test-only org.digimead.digi.lib.rudp.RUDPTest`

Please pay attention to `_j` suffix. It may be different in your case.

Updated:

There is a simple client/server test as example that uses MultiJVM: [RUDPTest](https://github.com/ezh/digi-lib-rudp/blob/19c83486885e4f7687106b0332624a336189af24/src/test/scala/org/digimead/digi/lib/rudp/RUDPTest.scala)

Comment: I have retained the defaults. You can see the project here https://github.com/NTCoding/akkesb

Comment: I clone your project. There are no defined tests. > show  multi-jvm:defined-tests
[info] List()

Comment: Your sent_commands_are_routed_to_registered_handlers.scala looks for me like a pack of applications. This is test that I run with multijvm - https://github.com/ezh/digi-lib-rudp/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/digimead/digi/lib/rudp/RUDPTest.scala. I think that you must change your code and make that your tests will be visible in show multi-jvm:defined-tests. I used scalatest, you use spec - IMHO this is not critical.

Comment: Nope, I converted them into FreeSpecLike tests but still not recognised

Comment: Yes, actually that does work if I convert them from objects to classes. Please change your answer to show this and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I am sorry Nick, but I don't understand how to update my answer. There is already part 2). You checked it (I am too) then you fixed your tests. There are a million ways for mistake. My answer is described checkpoints to troubleshoot such type of situation. I don't think that others will repeat your particular situation. If you sure that I am incorrect please edit my answer yourself.